# Parsing Parameters of a Powershell Script. How to do this from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

```
param(
    [string]$name,
    [string]$template
)
```

I have a powershell script with the following parameters. I am executing this powershell script from C#. I would like to parse the script and get the parameters. In future the script may change and so will the parameter count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = @"param([string]$name,[string]$template)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "\\[(?<type>\\w+)\\]\\$(?<name>\\w+)").OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(m => new 
                                {
                                   name = m.Groups["name"].Value, 
                                   type = m.Groups["type"].Value
                                });
foreach (var m in matches)
{
    // check m.name and m.type
}
```

Comment: the  OP says  In future the script may change and so will the parameter count. ???

Comment: @K.B. this code grab all params of type [type]$name, independent from param count

Comment: ok  well but what if  the params type change [integer]  for example it will  not work right ?

Comment: huuuum  give it a try

Comment: param([integer]$name,[string]$template) you mean? just checked, it works

Comment: I mean your regex it's not suitable for a future changement

Comment: @K.B you are free to suggest your version ;)

Comment: I'm not interested in that but  if you could make it a bit clever :)

Comment: @K.B say directly what you mean than

Comment: "\[[a-zA-Z]+\]\$" here just not optimized example

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the PowerShell Parser class for this.  The following example is in PowerShell for convenience but it could easily be done in C#:

```
PS> $str = 'param([string]$name,[string]$template)'
PS> $ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($str, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
PS> $ast.ParamBlock.Parameters.Name.Extent.Text
$name
$template
```